# cakephp: how to use or/and in conditions of $paginate

Tags: cakephp

actually,  i want to meet this sql requirement:

...  where  (type_id = 6 OR type_id = 8) and status = 2 ....

but i don NOT know how to set conditions in $paginate.

```
var $paginate = array(
        'Student'=>array(
                    'limit' => 10,
                    'fields'=>array('Student.id','Student.firstname','Student.lastname'),
                    'order' =>array('Student.id'=>'desc'),
                    'conditions' => ?,
                ),
        );
```

any one knows how to set conditions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this site http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions
(It's not the lastes release, but try it)

```
var $paginate = array(
        'Student'=>array(
                    'limit' => 10,
                    'fields'=>array('Student.id','Student.firstname','Student.lastname'),
                    'order' =>array('Student.id'=>'desc'),
                    'conditions' => array(
                         'Student.type_id' => array(6, 8),
                         'Student.status' => 2
                         )
                          
                ),
        );
```

or

```
var $paginate = array(
        'Student'=>array(
                    'limit' => 10,
                    'fields'=>array('Student.id','Student.firstname','Student.lastname'),
                    'order' =>array('Student.id'=>'desc'),
                    'conditions' => array(
                          'Student.status' => 2,
                          "OR" => array (
                               'Student.type_id' => 6,
                               'Student.type_id' => 8
                                )                             
                         )
                          
                ),
        );
```

**EDIT: This second version cannot be used in this situation, because now the OR array have two elements with the same keys and will check only the last (8)**

[N.B.] Excuse me if I made some syntax error :)

Comment: The docs for the latest release also show how to paginate with conditions: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#query-setup. Not sensing a lot of effort from OP :)